# For finite extension $L/K$, $ \operatorname{Gal}(L/K) \le [ L:K ]_s$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

For finite extension $L/K$, $ \operatorname{Gal}(L/K) \le [ L:K ]_s$?

I can't find this proof in my books.

Please show it.

Comment: What is your definition of $[L:K]_s$ ?

Comment: Which Definition do you use for the separability degree?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know another definition. $[L:K]_s$ is the degree of the separable closure S of $L/K$: $[L:K]_s = [S:K]$.

Comment: OK. Some people define it as the cardinality of the set of all homomorphisms of fields from $L$ to some algebraic closure $\overline{K}$ of $K$ containing $L$, which fix $K$.